# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ArrayofString' to 'string[]' in Console Application

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application

In WCF Project  i'm using the string[] function and calling that  string[] function  from console application by adding service reference. But shows error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ArrayofString' to 'string[]' in Console Application.

I can not solve this problem some times working fine if I recreate service reference it shows error as said above. Sample code is given below

```
public string[] SET_PROV_FROM_INVOICE(int type, int cust_id, int PLAN_ID, 
                    string INVOICE_ID, string IN_PARAMETER, string IN_FLD_ACTION,
                    string GET_VALUE, ref string RTN_VALUE) // invoice_id = Customer invoice table id , Cust_ID = Customer ID, type = 4  for Prov TagK
{
   System.Collections.ArrayList PROV_result = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
   return PROV_result.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
}

string[] ret_prov_tag = obj.SET_PROV_FROM_INVOICE(4, Convert.ToInt32(cust_id), 0, 
                                                  IN_FLD_INVOICE_ID, "", "Create", 
                                                  SET_VALUE, ref Prov_Rtn);
```

Comment: But where is the service reference call that you are referring to?

Comment: At last line used in console application by using obj calling that function

Comment: But this code compiles, there must be something that you are not telling us. Does `PROV_result` comes from service call?

Comment: ya above the last line , service reference project function, inside function adding the value in the array list and at last return the string[] by converting the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `ArrayOfString` to `string[]` using [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] ret_prov_tag = obj.SET_PROV_FROM_INVOICE(...).ToArray();
```